# Подключение и работа с MySQL на ооп php

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Я сейчас изучаю ооп в php и столкнулся с тем, что не знаю как правильно и грамотно подключиться к базе и работать с ней, используя именно ооп. Накидайте статей и примеров, кому не сложно, буду очень благодарен!
На данный момент я создал конфиг, в котором прописал название базы, имя пользователя, пароль и хост. Застрял на том, что нужно сделать класс, в нём методы подключения, вывода из базы нужной информации и метод сохранения туда новых данных.

Comment: https://php-start.com/lesson/php-start-practice/mvc-skeleton-part-1
можете много узнать здесь о ооп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$base.'', $user, $pass);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `as_items` LIMIT 0, 100') AS $row) {
print_r($row);
}
```

[Отсюда](https://www.khtulhu.org.ua/veb-programmirovanie/196-tri-sposoba-vyborki-iz-mysql.html)

Answer (score 1):

Если не использовать ORM то можно написать свою обертку над PDO
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

например https://stackoverflow.com/q/20664450/4128287

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри  этот  видео урок https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHrk5euM4-w&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXm69bqj5JTCS1XGTNkhTch&index=38 должен разобраться